# New Programmer/Multiple Scanner issue

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

SUPER beginner programmer and I am in the beginning of a intro to programming class based on java.   I am creating an average acceleration calculator using scanners and need some help because I am clueless to why its not working but here is how far i have gotten:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class averageAcceleration {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Scanner for Initial Velocity
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Inital Velocity-->>");
    int vI = in.nextInt();
    in.close();

    // Scanner for Final Velocity
    Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Final Velocity-->>");
    int vF = in1.nextInt();
    in1.close();

    //Scanner for Time in seconds
    Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Time in Seconds-->>");
    int tS = in2.nextInt();
    in2.close();

    double averageAcceleration = (vF - vI) / tS;
    System.out.print("Inital Velocity is " + vI + "Final Velocity is " + vF + "Time is " + tS);
    System.out.print("Average Acceleration is " + averageAcceleration);
```

Comment: are you getting any error? what is the exact issue that you are facing? i would advice to start small.. write one line, execute and verify write another and verify and so forth..

Comment: @JosAngelGeorge I get a blank error box with my code and Sweeper 's code which is a logic error but i have no clue what is wrong.

Comment: The answer below fixes your `Scanner` issue; or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are closing the scanners before creating a new one. When you `close` a scanner, the underlying stream gets closed as well, in this case it is `System.in`. You then proceed to create a new scanner with `System.in`, which is already closed. Obviously, creating a scanner with a closed stream won't work.

Just do everything with one scanner, there's nothing wrong with it.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Inital Velocity-->>");
int vI = in.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter Final Velocity-->>");
int vF = in.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter Time in Seconds-->>");
int tS = in.nextInt();

double averageAcceleration = (vF - vI) / tS;
System.out.print("Inital Velocity is " + vI + "Final Velocity is " + vF + "Time is " + tS);
System.out.print("Average Acceleration is " + averageAcceleration);
```

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there wasn't a duplicate of this.